# Can Autosys Job exec a Stored procedure with dynamic parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, global-variables, autosys, jil

Can Autosys jobs execute a stored procedure with dynamic parameters

Comment: Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will most likely need to create a shell script that takes the parameters, authenticates to your database, calls the stored proc, and passes it the parameters. Then script your jil to execute the shell script with the desired parameters.